# plupload - how to set where files are uploaded to?

Tags: php, file-upload, plupload

I've just installed the latest version of plupload to my local test PHP server, running the HTML5 uploader. Everything seemingly works ok however I cannot determine where the files are being uploaded to (and how to change this to a directory that I would like to set).

Here is the file - http://jsfiddle.net/SQ9aB/

Comment: Which URL to send the request to, or which directory on the server to store them after they're uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url is in the property "url" of your configuration object.

```
$("#html5_uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5',
    url : 'upload.php',
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    chunk_size : '1mb',
    unique_names : true,
....
```

in this case to upload.php

Comment: When I view the upload.php and var_dump the var $targetDir it returns the following:    
    D:\Program Files\xampp\tmp\plupload

This would seem to be the temp folder where files are saved - does anyone how I set the destination folder for images

Comment: @Zabs upload.php are including some others files? if its the only file, you must find $targetDir declaration.

Comment: its just the upload.php - you are right it will be in $targetDir variable - will look into and see how i get on.

Comment: In the console log - get the following

`{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}`

Comment: @Zabs - it does upload to a temporary directory then requires an additional form post to actually save the files to a specified directly. Not entirely sure why they structured it this way out of the box but you can modify as needed if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

For the other side of the equation (change where the file go once they're uploaded) and assuming you're using the examples provided with plupload, open `upload.php` and change this line:

```
$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
```

It should be right at the top of the file below `header()` calls, but that will change where the files go once they're uploaded.

There is also this portion towards the bottom of the file (which is strange because *usually* PHP files use `move_uploaded_file` instead of reading from `php://input`, sorting to a `.part` file and `fread`/`fwrite`ing the contents):

```
// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}
```

It looks like it takes everything out of the stream as best it can, creates a ".part" file storing this (for incomplete uploads I would guess?) then just renames it within the current directory. Again, strange, but to each his/her own I guess.

Answer (score 1):

managed to use the following in the $targetDir var to get it working.. hopefully I will save someone one time looking at the same problem

`$targetDir = realpath(getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT")) . '\uploads';`

Answer (score 1):

In the `upload.php` file in the new versions of Plupload it should have a line conmmented out like so:

`// $targetDir = 'uploads';`

Just remove the `//` and save the file (of course you will need to create directory named `uploads` inside the examples folder.)

Comment: this one help me. thanks alot. spend 3 hours for looking the answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

For laravel (or any similar MVC frameworks):

`url : /to-your-route`

In your controller

```
$foldername = "yourFolderName";
$filename = $request->name;

    return Plupload::receive('file', function ($file) use ($foldername,$filename)
    {

        $file->move(public_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$foldername.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $filename);
        return ['result'=>'result','filename'=>$filename];


    });
```